# Data Driven Technology (Excel Data Pass)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I'm Passing username and password through Excel then it shows error as invalid credentials 
But if I sent same data by sendkeys It accepts that data

Selenium Data Driven

Comment: can you show your code ?

Comment: Solved the issue i was sending integer value through excel so before that values i have to write * sign